# selecting edges based on source/target in igraph

Tags: python, igraph

is there an easy way to select/delete edges based on their source and target in igraph?

what I am using is essentially

```
g.es["source"] = [e.source for e in g.es]
g.es["target"] = [e.target for e in g.es]    
g.es["tuple"]  = [e.tuple  for e in g.es]        

g.es.select(target=root)
```

but I feel like there should be a way to do that without storing source/target info twice.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just use `_source=whatever` and `_target=whatever` as keyword arguments to `select`, e.g.:

```
g.es.select(_source=root)
```

Alternatively, you can use the `incident` method of the graph, which gives you a list of edge IDs instead of a filtered `EdgeSeq` if that is better for your purposes:

```
g.incident(root, mode="out")
```

Comment: thanks! I actually realized that your solutions only work with igraph 0.6 and the version I used (the one in the ubuntu main repository) is outdated.

Comment: A possible workaround is to use igraph's own PPA which always contains the most recent stable version: https://launchpad.net/~igraph/+archive/ppa

Comment: This seems like it would be inefficient. Is it a constant-time lookup if you specify both the source and target?

Comment: Nope; in that case, you are better off with `g.es[g.get_eid(source, target)]`, which is something like `O(log d)`, where `d` is the smaller of the degrees of the two vertices involved.

Comment: Note that g.get_eid returns only one index even if there are multiple edges between those two nodes.

Comment: is there a way to select based on the name of the vertex? E.g., g.es.select(_source="v1").

Answer (score 2):

BTW, for 'tuple', you want to use `_between`:

```
g.es.find(_between=((source_id,), (target_id,)))
```

It looks strange - if you use `select` instead of `find`, and pass in tuples with multiple indices, you'll actually get a list of edges instead of a single one. But for a single edge, have to still pass a tuple for start and end.

This is way faster for some reason (like, 3 orders of magnitude faster!) than using a combination of `_source` and `_target`, but gives the exact same information.

Comment: Note that this approach works in undirected graphs and in graphs without parallel edges. If two edges exist between two nodes (such as in directed graphs or in undirected graphs with parallel edges), only one arbitrary edge will be returned by this call

Comment: good point... it isn't really source_id and target_id: in my directed graph, i rarely have paths going both directions, but i do in one case. in that case, `_between` always returns one of those edges, whichever order i put the 'source'/'target'. however: `g.es.find(_source=s, _target=t)` = 22.7 ms, `g.es.find(_between=((s,),(t,)))` = 293 uS, `g.get_eid(s, t)` = 342 nS, so maybe that's the best general method.